# Dragging an edge from a button in a context menu of a node

Tags: reactjs, html5-canvas, vis.js

My use-case is as follows

- Click on a node to see a context menu
- In that, there is an option to drag an edge using the current selected node as source *(currently I enable addEdgeMode())*
- Once I click that, I want to be able to drag an edge to a target node without clicking the source node again.

I am unable to figure out a way to automatically touch the source node on which this context menu option is clicked. I think there is an issue already:
https://github.com/visjs/vis-network/issues/769

Is there a way to achieve this by any chance? I don't want to keep the addEdgeNode enabled forever because then it disables the entire physics and everything and also might hijack the node clicks. Unsure about the latter though.

- I tried shooting the following events with a custom event object in this order which doesn't work.

```
net.manipulation._controlNodeTouch
net.manipulation._handleConnect
net.manipulation._dragStartEdge
net.manipulation._dragControlNode
```

- Tried simulating a canvas click with bubbling enabled

Any help here would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like this isn't something available natively.